# Display multiple yes/no fields in single line

Tags: vba, ms-access, for-loop

i Have a table Tools where there are 15 yes/no fields. User checks which tools were used in an event. Could be one or more, or none. There are other fields in the table, but all the relevant field names start with tblTool

In report I'd like to display the tools in single line, Something like 'Tools used: hammer, chisel...'

My current solution for this is a bunch of if statements that check each item and add it to the variable if it's positive. My question is this, is there a simpler way? some kind of a loop that would check all the field names in a certain table that start with the same string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might have solved this

```
txt = ""
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from ops where opID = " & Me.opID)
Dim fld As DAO.Field
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
    If Left(fld.Name, 5) = "opImp" Then
        If fld = True Then
        txt = txt & fld.Name
        End If
        End If
Next
Set fld = Nothing
```

Comment: Yep, I was going to suggest looping the Recordset.Fields collection. :-)

Comment: a sub-question. when I change the record in the form, through record chooser at the bottom, this calculated data still points to the previous record, even though all bound data changes. What do I have to do so that this is recalculated? I tried onload and onupdate events without success.

Comment: The `OnCurrent` event is triggered, when you move to a different record in a bound form